# how to make work jasmine-ajax with grunt-contrib-jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I am trying to use the [jasmine-ajax library](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax) to mock ajax request with [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine), but it seems jasmine is not able to find the library (it says jasmine.Ajax is not defined).

my grunt file:

```
   jasmine: {
            test:{
                src :[ '<%= watch.files %>'],
                options: {
                    vendor: 'vendor/mock-ajax.js',
                    specs : ['specs/**/*spec.js'],
                    helpers : 'specs/helpers/*.js',
                    timeout : 10000
                }
            }
```

I downloaded mock-ajax.js and put it in a vendor folder. this is the part of the test where the error appears:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
            jasmine.Ajax.install();
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved.. for the interest of others with the same problem: 
the file in https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax/blob/master/lib/mock-ajax.js did not worked for me. 
I installed jasmine-ajax via npm and then referenced its version of mock-ajax.js from the gruntfile: 
vendor: ['node_modules/jasmine-ajax/lib/mock-ajax.js'],

thanks to jsoverson for the hints in checking the paths (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/issues/111#issuecomment-51806488)

Comment: I am also trying the same thing but unable to make it work. My Gruntfile and node_modules are in the same parent directory. I installed using command "npm install jasmin-ajax" and gave the same vendor path as you mentioned, but it is giving error. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

this is the setup of a recent project, I just tested with a fresh "git clone", "npm install", "grunt test", it works out of the box! hope it helps:

```
  jasmine: {
      test:{
        src :[
          '<%= watch.files %>'
        ],
        options: {
          vendor: ['node_modules/jasmine-ajax/lib/mock-ajax.js',
                   'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                   'node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
                   'node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js',
                  ],
          specs : ['spec/helpers/*.js',
                   'spec/**/*spec.js'],
          helpers : ['spec/helpers/*.js'],
          timeout : 10000,
          keepRunner: true
        }
      },
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but following is my code which is not working. Any idea?
        jasmine: {
            src: 'dist/production.js',
            options: {
                specs: 'test/**/*.js',
                styles: 'styles/**/*.css',
                vendor: ["node_modules/jasmine-ajax/lib/mock-ajax.js"],
                template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs')
            }
        },

Comment: what are your exact error message? check your _SpecRunner.html file, the line  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-ajax/lib/mock-ajax.js"></script> should appears there, just before your scripts. check that node_modules did contains the file in the expected path. tip: check your _specRunner.html in the browser, with inspector tools, running a local web server at the root of your project.